# Changing the package.xml version to a different version

Tags: api, package.xml

We have been performing out deployments with a package.xml that had a version of 42.0 and it was metadata API format scaffolding but we are trying to create a new deployment pipeline which will have a a source format. I am trying to change the version setting to 47.0. Is it going to impact anything.Is it going to deploy everything in my org with version 47.0?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it going to impact anything. Is it going to deploy everything in my org with version 47.0?

You will be talking to version 47.0 of the Metadata API. Your components must be valid and well-formed as of that API version. However, note that your Apex components' own API versions will *not* be upgraded.

I tend to see problems with API version upgrades for `package.xml` on declarative metadata. When you run your first deploys, you may see errors indicating that specific tags in your declarative metadata have been deprecated and must be removed. For example, the property `mobileReady` on `CustomTab`s is not valid in 47.0, nor `tab` on `CustomApplication`.

If your metadata contains any properties that were legal on 42.0 and are not on 47.0 (I don't know off the top of my head if that's a non-empty set), you'll simply need to remove them where they're called out in Metadata API errors.

Comment: I think specifically the ValueSet specifications may have changed around that time, so any objects with picklist values may fail to deploy.

Comment: I think that change was in API ~38.0, but I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed for your prompt response. So I take it that our Apex components' own API versions will not be upgraded.Will check the deployments as well.Thanks Again.

Comment: @Chetan I recommend at least doing a force:mdapi:retrieve with the upgraded package version so you can compare any diffs before committing.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for the recommendation. but I was just wondering since I am going to retrieve everything first(sfdx:force:source:retrieve -x manifest/package.xml) from my Org with version 47.0 and put it onto a master branch, so once I make a deployment(sfdx:force:source:deploy -x manifest/package.xml) it ideally should not throw the errors which David mentioned. No?

Comment: @Chetan Yes, if you're doing a retrieve anyways, you'll be fine.